# Flutter Memory Event in DevTools when animation

Tags: performance, flutter, memory, devtools

I have a question when I monitor project performance by DevTools on Flutter.

I found when animation running, it has many purple tringles "event" on the memory page.
These events detail are Flutter.ImageSizesForFrame assets/bg.jpg (it is my background image, not animation)

Is it an issue? is that mean flutter decode bg.jpg again and again when animation running?

[image]